# How to recognize and count circles in a rectangle?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I would like to count how many circles are in static rectangles for more than 3 seconds. The circles represent the center of objects recognized by the camera and static rectangles are areas of interest where I would like to count the total amount of circles that are inside the area of interest for more than 3 seconds. Currently I am able to recognize objects in real-time, find the center of each object and draw static rectangles, but I don't know how to do the rest. Below is my current while loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=720)

    box_one = cv2.rectangle(frame, (30,30), (330,330), color, 2)
    box_two = cv2.rectangle(frame, (350,30), (630,330), color, 2)

    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)),
        0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx],
                confidence * 100)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
                COLORS[idx], 2)

            center = ((startX+endX)/2, (startY+endY)/2)
            first_value = int(center[0])
            second_value = int(center[1])
            coordinates = (first_value, second_value)
            cv2.circle(frame, coordinates, 5, (255,255,255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

The output looks like this

[image: 1]]

Comment: How can anyone help you without seeing your image? Please add a representative one, thanks.

Comment: The frame is a the threaded video stream, I'm not sure what you mean by image.

Comment: Exactly - please provide such a frame from one of your real-life video streams.

Comment: This could be used as an example https://ak7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1385887/thumb/1.jpg

Comment: And now, please explain which "circles" you want to have extracted over time. The traffic signs?

Comment: The people entering in rectangles.

Comment: I dont see any obvious circles there to detect. Only the traffic light lights and the traffix signs maybe... or the backsides of the heads?

Comment: The circle represents the center of each object. Instead of counting how many whole objects fit in one rectangle, the circles are counted. And the detection model isn't that sophisticated where it can distinguish the difference between a person and the back of the head, therefor the whole object is labeled as a person.

Comment: The circles are confusing. Could you either draw it out on that image or provide maybe draw the output of your program so far.

Comment: This is how the current output looks like https://i.imgur.com/MuGuEbh.jpg